# Production django server throwing "NoReverseMatch" while rendering, works on development

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.main' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I don't understand what would cause the error.

My urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.main),
```

html template

```
<a href="{% url views.main %}"> bla bla blah</a>
```

And in my views.py

```
return render_to_response("main.html", d, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've checked my TEMPLATE_DIRS and they seem to be pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: Are you using the same django version in dev and prod? What is the webserver you're using in prod?

Comment: Both are DJango 1.2.3 My production server is apache/django.wsgi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likelihood is that you have an error somewhere else, which is preventing one of your views from being imported - probably a dependency missing on your production server. The reverse-URL functionality works by importing all your views, so if any of them can't be imported for any reason you'll see a `NoReverseMatch` error.

Comment: It wasn't a missing dependency. Indeed, I have no idea what was causing the problem. I did a refresh of my production image and was able to get rolling just fine. I wish I had more to report back to future SO'ers.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
url(r'^$', views.main, name="main-view")
```

and on template:

```
<a href="{% url main-view %}"> bla bla blah</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing, and so I tried Paperino's method of creating an image of the server and then restoring the server to that image, and voila, the template error went away.  I have no idea why that works, but it did for me, so I'm not complaining, spent most of the day trying to figure this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting `gunicorn` service solved my problem:

`sudo systemctl restart YOUR_GUNICORN.service`

Make sure that you are restarting the **right gunicorn** service. I was driving myself insane, and then I realized I was restarting the wrong service. You might also try restartingrestart nginx, but it shouldn't be necesary: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`